# Functional MD complex RAID10 suddenly marks all drives as spares

Tags: linux, raid, nas, storage, mdadm

This morning during a long ~1.5TB read operation sending data to an NFS client, my md complex-RAID10 array spontaneously stopped, then dropped four members for being "non-fresh" and failed to start again. Checking mdstat shows all drives considered "spares".

Running on Debian 7. 6x HGST Deskstar NAS, four running on a Marvell 88SE9230 PCIe add-in card and two on the internal ICH7 SATA. All drives pass SMART with no reallocations. The four drives that were dropped were all on the Marvell card but are also sda, sdb, sdc, and sdd and I have a feeling it's not necessarily the controller, which I have tested and continues to work fine.

I believe all the data on this array should be backed up, but I am not sure and all the data it would be handling is of extreme importance. My storage workflow is in transition right now and the backups for this data are all over the place.

How can I get this thing started again? Some have suggested failing and removing each drive and re-adding it, some have suggested starting the array with --force, and others still have said to recreate the array with --assume-clean, but all have experience only with other RAID levels. They, and I, have no idea how those would behave with a complex RAID10 and it doesn't seem good.

[UPDATE]
I discovered that the device names had changed. That's why the OS drive is sdg in mdstat (after reboot) and it's sdc in the syslog (hence the EXT4 mount message). Now I don't believe the four that got kicked out were all on the Marvell controller.

I stopped the 1/3-assembled array and --assemble --scan showed four drives "(possibly out of date)" and it couldn't build from the remaining two. I tried again manually using --assemble --force and it cleared the FAULTY flags, assembled from 6 drives, but still couldn't start the array because all of them are still marked SPARE. So this leaves me with the step of how to get these drives recognized again as their respective functional members of this RAID10, if that's possible...

```
mdstat:

md0 : inactive sdf[0](S) sdd[5](S) sdc[4](S) sdb[3](S) sda[2](S) sde[1](S)
      23441325072 blocks super 1.2


syslog:

    Dec 13 02:30:02 mWproduction rpc.mountd[2790]: authenticated mount request from 10.10.1.124:993 for /media/MainStore (/media/MainStore)
    Dec 13 02:33:22 mWproduction kernel: [ 2238.437611] md: md0 stopped.
    Dec 13 02:33:22 mWproduction kernel: [ 2238.437628] md: unbind
    Dec 13 02:33:22 mWproduction kernel: [ 2238.456050] md: export_rdev(sdf)
    Dec 13 02:33:22 mWproduction kernel: [ 2238.456131] md: unbind
    Dec 13 02:33:22 mWproduction kernel: [ 2238.472043] md: export_rdev(sdd)
    Dec 13 02:33:22 mWproduction kernel: [ 2238.472130] md: unbind
    Dec 13 02:33:22 mWproduction kernel: [ 2238.472183] md: export_rdev(sdc)
    Dec 13 02:33:22 mWproduction kernel: [ 2238.472233] md: unbind
    Dec 13 02:33:22 mWproduction kernel: [ 2238.476282] md: export_rdev(sdb)
    Dec 13 02:33:22 mWproduction kernel: [ 2238.476329] md: unbind
    Dec 13 02:33:22 mWproduction kernel: [ 2238.476369] md: export_rdev(sda)
    Dec 13 02:33:22 mWproduction kernel: [ 2238.476421] md: unbind
    Dec 13 02:33:22 mWproduction kernel: [ 2238.480171] md: export_rdev(sde)
    Dec 13 02:33:27 mWproduction kernel: [ 2243.889311] md: md0 stopped.
    Dec 13 02:33:27 mWproduction kernel: [ 2243.890748] md: bind
    Dec 13 02:33:27 mWproduction kernel: [ 2243.890902] md: bind
    Dec 13 02:33:27 mWproduction kernel: [ 2243.891047] md: bind
    Dec 13 02:33:27 mWproduction kernel: [ 2243.891190] md: bind
    Dec 13 02:33:27 mWproduction kernel: [ 2243.891327] md: bind
    Dec 13 02:33:27 mWproduction kernel: [ 2243.891503] md: bind
    Dec 13 02:33:27 mWproduction kernel: [ 2243.891528] md: kicking non-fresh sdd from array!
    Dec 13 02:33:27 mWproduction kernel: [ 2243.891534] md: unbind
    Dec 13 02:33:27 mWproduction kernel: [ 2243.904065] md: export_rdev(sdd)
    Dec 13 02:33:27 mWproduction kernel: [ 2243.904079] md: kicking non-fresh sdc from array!
    Dec 13 02:33:27 mWproduction kernel: [ 2243.904090] md: unbind
    Dec 13 02:33:27 mWproduction kernel: [ 2243.916138] md: export_rdev(sdc)
    Dec 13 02:33:27 mWproduction kernel: [ 2243.916155] md: kicking non-fresh sdb from array!
    Dec 13 02:33:27 mWproduction kernel: [ 2243.916173] md: unbind
    Dec 13 02:33:27 mWproduction kernel: [ 2243.928029] md: export_rdev(sdb)
    Dec 13 02:33:27 mWproduction kernel: [ 2243.928039] md: kicking non-fresh sda from array!
    Dec 13 02:33:27 mWproduction kernel: [ 2243.928046] md: unbind
    Dec 13 02:33:27 mWproduction kernel: [ 2243.944040] md: export_rdev(sda)
    Dec 13 02:33:27 mWproduction kernel: [ 2243.962667] md: raid10 personality registered for level 10
    Dec 13 02:33:27 mWproduction kernel: [ 2243.963132] bio: create slab  at 1
    Dec 13 02:33:27 mWproduction kernel: [ 2243.967055] md/raid10:md0: not enough operational mirrors.
    Dec 13 02:33:27 mWproduction kernel: [ 2243.967264] md: pers->run() failed ...
    Dec 13 02:33:35 mWproduction kernel: [ 2251.460454] md: md0 stopped.
    Dec 13 02:33:35 mWproduction kernel: [ 2251.460465] md: unbind
    Dec 13 02:33:35 mWproduction kernel: [ 2251.480313] md: export_rdev(sdf)
    Dec 13 02:33:35 mWproduction kernel: [ 2251.480476] md: unbind
    Dec 13 02:33:35 mWproduction kernel: [ 2251.498418] md: export_rdev(sde)
    Dec 13 02:33:44 mWproduction kernel: [ 2260.905447] md: md0 stopped.
    Dec 13 02:33:44 mWproduction kernel: [ 2260.911283] md: bind
    Dec 13 02:33:44 mWproduction kernel: [ 2260.911576] md: bind
    Dec 13 02:33:44 mWproduction kernel: [ 2260.911844] md: bind
    Dec 13 02:33:44 mWproduction kernel: [ 2260.912306] md: bind
    Dec 13 02:33:44 mWproduction kernel: [ 2260.912475] md: bind
    Dec 13 02:33:44 mWproduction kernel: [ 2260.912650] md: bind
    Dec 13 02:42:48 mWproduction shutdown[4245]: shutting down for system reboot
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is resolved. I was advised to perform mdadm -E on all drives. It revealed that, now that the array was force-reassembled, all but one of the drives had an array-status of AAAAAA. `/dev/sde` had its status stuck on AA.... (two active, four inactive) and that indicated some sort of anomaly.

I reassembled the drives, without `--force`, omitting `/dev/sde` and it indicated it needed `--run` because it wanted all members present. With --run, the array started correctly, degraded. Now I am testing the remaining disk, double-checking that everything is backed up, and re-adding it to the array.

Big, big thanks to users spreeuw and mumixam of irc.freenode.net #linux and #mdadm respectively for their valuable input.